# nullPointerException in Android when trying to get an xml response from a server

Tags: android

I am developing an Horoscope application, which when tapped on an image should send a request to a server and get an xml response.
But I am not getting any xml response. I am using GET method. Please help me out in this.

Thanks

Comment: You should post your code and the exception trace...

Answer (score 1):

Network operations must not be performed on the main UI thread. You could use `AsyncTask` to perform network operation in another thread.

Comment: While I get the point of your answer, I'd like to say that it can easily be misunderstood. It's simply not true that netowrk operations must be done in AsyncTask on Android. What _is_ true is that network operations must not be performed on the main UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Class Stacker. I'll gonna improve my post.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

But to be honest, it is better to not use the first option, but the second option.

//===========================================================================
 Option 2:

Used this tutorial to make a proper ASyncTask: http://www.elvenware.com/charlie/development/android/SimpleHttpGetThread.html

//===========================================================================
 Used ASyncTask as final (option 2).

Comment: `StictMode.` type solutions really should be avoided. AsyncTask is there for these kinds of tasks.